# What's a fast way to collect most-used words on a page?

Tags: javascript, dom, keyword

I need to get a "keyword breakdown" of a page. Bonus: It needs to be very fast.

Should I scan the DOM only for text nodes to improve speed? Not really sure how to approach this.

Comment: The best would be to do some tests: http://jsperf.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd probably be best off to do `innerText`/`textContent` and then split up words. Looking for text nodes will break if a word is split up (half a word is bold) or something. It also moves the DOM traversal into JS instead of C++.

```
var content = document.body.innerText || document.body.textContent;
var words = content.match(/\b\w+\b/g);

var counts = {};
for (var i = 0, len = words.length; i < len; i++){
  var word = words[i];
  counts[word] = (counts[word] || 0) + 1;
}

console.log(words);
```

It can, however, be tough to guess on performance without just trying it and then benchmarking, so really I'd say just give it your best shot and go from there.

Comment: And you have to use `.textContent` in Firefox.

Comment: @FelixKling Good call, I'm too used to Chrome :P

Comment: The downside of this is that words can be combined in `textContent` (and `innerText`, depending on the browser). For example, for the following HTML: `"<div><p>One two</p><p>Three four</p></div>"`, the `<div>` element has `texContent` "One twoThree four".